# MemTest86 200 errors after 4 passes in dual channel only - should I worry?

Tags: memtest

12700F
MSI PRO B660M-A DDR4
2x8GB G.skill Neo 3600hz cl18
XMP enabled, DIMM voltage is 1.35V

At first I had about 800 errors after 4 passes, so I tried testing each stick individually and there were no errors with each stick alone even in different sockets.

For dual channel, I read that I should try increasing the voltage, but it didn't help (at 1.37V). I also read that I should try loosening the CPU cooler, and it helped a bit - there are now about 200 errors after 4 passes.

Should I worry? The PC is brand new (about 2 weeks old) and I haven't seen a BSOD yet (but I also haven't put it under serious load yet).

Comment: You should not get significant errors running Memtest.  I would document your test and return the computer for a new one.

Comment: @John Are there insignificant errors in Memtest? How to tell if an error is significant?

Comment: When I have tested good memory, I do not see the level of errors stated in the question. There is not way I know (short of Memtest stopping) to tell if an error is significant or not.

Comment: @John I have the HTML report, what part of it tells me whether the errors are significant or not?

Comment: I don't know if Memtest can sort errors between significant and insignificant.  I would definitely report to the manufacturer.

Comment: "*there were no errors with each stick alone even in different sockets.*" -- So perform a test of multiple memory modules in *single*-channel mode, i.e. not dual-channel mode.  Avoid fingerprints (i.e. skin oils) on the contacts; clean the contacts if necessary.

Comment: @sawdust will do - thanks :)

Comment: @sawdust I moved both to the B slots and no change - same amount of errors more or less. Tried with XMP disabled and enabled, lowered and increased DIMM voltage, loosened and tightened the CPU cooler - no improvement. Same with back to dual channel

Comment: Try resetting the BIOS to default mode as well as force a memory retrain.

Comment: @sawdust what does memory retrain mean? I guess not to restart the system?

Comment: Search for the numerous (eleven) mentions of `train` in the [MSI Intel 600 BIOS User Guide](http://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/mb/Intel600BIOS.pdf)  You might also check if there is a BIOS update for that mobo.

Comment: @sawdust thanks! From what I saw, all I had to do was disable Memory Fast Boot. But the errors remain.. should I get a new kit?

Comment: Have you verified that this memory kit is listed as compatible with this motherboard?  Since single-channel mode has issues, then something is fundamentally broken IMO.  Maybe one more test using the `A` sockets?

Comment: @sawdust according to pangoly.com it is. I'll test single channel on the As, why not

Comment: "*according to pangoly.com it is*" -- A retail site is not authoratative.  The MSI documentation does not list a "*2x8GB G.skill Neo 3600hz cl18*" as compatible memory for that motherboard.  In fact a google search indicates that such memory might be only DDR4, and not the DDR5 required.

Comment: @sawdust It's DDR4. The exact model is F4-3600C18D-16GTZN . About the A sockets - I tested both sticks one at a time in both sockets for 4 passes each, 0 errors. I put both sticks in the the A sockets together - 240 errors in the first minute of the first pass.

Comment: @sawdust Ok yeah, the model is not supported. Just searched for it here: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/PRO-B660M-A-DDR4/support#mem I guess this means I need to replace the kit

Comment: Apparently there are two versions of "*B660M-A Pro*": one that uses DDR4, and another that uses DDR5.  Your post needs to more specific.

Comment: @sawdust my bad, had no idea, I'm sorry. Will add to the post.

Comment: @sawdust although I think I was wrong and the RAM is indeed compatible - I can find the model number F4-3600C18Q-32GTZR in there which is basically the same, only difference is that it's 4x8GB (Q means quad- 4 sticks in the package, my D version means double- 2 sticks in the package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for my specific model in the supported memory section in the manufacturer's website.

Specifically, I searched for `F4-3600C18D-16GTZN`, which is the problematic model, here: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/PRO-B660M-A-DDR4/support#mem

I realized that the chip probably is not yet supported by the board, so I replaced it with a model that is.

One very important thing that I learned from this and is very important to note is that different kits of the same model can be made of different chipsets, so it's always important to not mix modules from different kits, even if they're the same model.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not tested to be compatible. That doesn't necessarily mean it's not supported, although it may be. (it may also be faulty)

Answer (score 1):

Usually these types of errors come down to memory timings.
In some modern BIOS there are actually 20+ different timings you can set.

You can read a number of these timings with CPU-Z and the memory tab vs the SPD tab.

First compare all the SPD from the memory chip itself with your BIOS settings.

You will probably discover you need to increase some of these setting by a little bit.